# widgets defined out of scope

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I wrote the code below to link the creation of some widgets to the value of another widget. Trouble is I'm now unable to access the values of the widgets created in `return_widgets` as they are out of scope of the main programme. How do I access these widgets, or more specifically the values of these widgets? I've tried having the `on_value_change` function return the widgets, but can't work out how to assign them to anything given that the only place that function is called is in the `observe` statement.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def return_widgets(size):
    return [widgets.IntText(value=x) for x in range(size)]

out = widgets.Output()
def on_value_change(change):
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
       w = return_widgets(change['new'])
       display(*w)

size = widgets.IntText(value=3, min=1, max=5, description='size')

size.observe(on_value_change, 'value')
widgets.VBox([size, out])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that scope is the issue here, the variable names are created within the function scope and then lost when the function returns.

One solution would be to maintain a dictionary of widgets at the global level, and write into this dict whenever you change the number of desired widgets.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

widget_dict = {}

def return_widgets(size):
    return {str(x): widgets.IntText(description=str(x), value=x) for x in range(size)}

out = widgets.Output()
def on_value_change(change):
    out.clear_output()
    w = return_widgets(change['new'])
    for k,v in w.items():
        widget_dict[k] = v
    with out:
        display(*w.values())

size = widgets.IntText(value=3, min=1, max=5, description='size')

size.observe(on_value_change, 'value')
widgets.VBox([size, out])
```